# Is it possible in doxygen to link to a local variable

Tags: c, doxygen

Is it possible to create a link in the doxygen docu to a local variable?

For example:

```
/*!
 *  The variable \ref testVar is a test variable.
 */
void testFunc()
{
    int testVar = 0;
}
```

I know it`s possible to link to a global variable, but is this even possible?

Comment: What do you mean with: to link? Could you elaborate?

Comment: When I read the doxygen docu I want to click on the testVarit will lead me to the variable testvar

Comment: You can't do it for local vars.

Comment: Ok, thats what my question is about. So there is no way to get it? Something like \ref testFunc::testVar?

Comment: No, AFAIK you can't do that.